# React Native TextInput ref always undefined

Tags: react-native, react-ref

I have a simple TextInput that I want to put a reference on in my render:

```
      <View>
        <TextInput ref={(component) => this._inputElement = component}>Input</TextInput>
        {console.log(this._inputElement)}
        <Button
          onPress={this.addAddress}
          title="Submit"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
```

I want to then use that ref in a function above that is bound in my contructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      addresses: []
    };

    this.addAddress = this.addAddress.bind(this);
  }
```

addAddress function:

```
  addAddress(event, result) {
    console.log("reference:", this._inputElement.value);
  }
```

The console log in both the render and addAddress are always undefined.

I have looked around but no one seems to be having my problem, usually they have a typo or didn't bind the function they then want to call.

Why do I seem unable to have references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using State

Usually the way to use `TextInput` is to store the value in state.

Remember to initialize the address in your state as an empty string, otherwise having a null value for address could cause an error.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   ....
   address: ''
  }
}
```

Then you could define your text input as follows

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={address => this.setState({address})}
  value={this.state.address}
/>
```

Then in your addAddress

```
addAddress(event, result) {
  console.log("reference:", this.state.address);
}
```

## Using Refs

Alternatively you could use `._lastNativeText` to access it from the reference

```
<TextInput 
  ref={ref => { this._inputElement = ref }}>
  Input
</TextInput>
```

then in your addAddress

```
addAddress(event, result) {
  // I always check to make sure that the ref exists
  if (this._inputElement) {
    console.log("reference:", this._inputElement._lastNativeText);
  }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend the second method as you are accessing private methods that could be liable to change in a future release.

Comment: For me `._lastNativeText` is always undefined

Comment: As I said, I wouldn't recommend using that method, it is a private method and it may have changed or it may no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Textinput self-encloses

```
<View>
        <TextInput ref={ref=> (this._inputElement = ref)}/>
        <Button
          onPress={this.addAddress}
          title="Submit"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>


addAddress(event, result) {
    console.log("reference:", this._inputElement._lastNativeText); //this get's the value, otherwise it's undefined
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that did work, wish I could give a correct answer to both!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works properly in react native and react native web:

```
    const txtRef = useRef(null)
    return(
    <TextInput
      ref={txtRef}
      onChangeText={text => txtRef.current.value = text}
    />

    <Button
      title='log and reset'
      onPress={() => {
        console.log(txtRef.current.value)
        txtRef.current.clear()
        txtRef.current.value = ''
    }}
    />
    )
```

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).